# Is there a way to make a Field Label a filter in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau and am curious if it is possible to embed a filter into a Row Field Label? In the attached picture below, you can see that the filters match the separate columns in the chart created. Is there a way to basically embed that filter look directly into that header row, or is my best way going to be to just hide the top row and keep the filters sized like that? I am hoping there is a better way to make it look better and more in sync.

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your hiding the header idea might be the only way.

In addition to your suggestion, you might try adding a blank section of dashboard above your data and **floating** the filters so they can be very accurately placed. I would also suggest using the arrow keys to move them a pixel at a time.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thank you for the floating advice, that makes it look pretty clean!